# Bash script for reviewing .pdf articles

Tags: bash, pdf

I wrote a bash script for reviewing scientific articles. It adds a blank page for notes and creates a new landscape file. I'm sure it can be made better code wise. Any suggestions?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage example: ./bashscript src.pdf"
  exit $E_BADARGS
else
  NUM=$(pdftk $1 dump_data | grep 'NumberOfPages' | awk '{split($0,a,": "); print a[2]}')
  COMMSTR=''

  for i in $(seq 1 $NUM);
  do
    COMMSTR="$COMMSTR A$i B1 " 
  done
  $(echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - pageblanche.pdf)
  $(pdftk A=$1 B=pageblanche.pdf cat $COMMSTR output 'mod_'$1)
  (pdfnup 'mod_'$1 --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile 'print_'$1)
  $(rm pageblanche.pdf && rm 'mod_'$1)

fi

#for f in *.pdf; do ./bashscript.sh $f; done 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all "bashscript" is a very poor name:

- It doesn't tell what the script does. "prepare-articles-for-review.sh" would be better. Or just "prepare-articles.sh"
- It is customer to use `.sh` extension for Bash scripts

---

If your typical use case is this:

> ```
> for f in *.pdf; do ./bashscript.sh $f; done 2> /dev/null
> ```

Then it would be better to make the script handle multiple file parameters.

---

> ```
>   exit $E_BADARGS
> ```

I'm not familiar with such variable. I don't think it's a standard, and it's not mentioned in my `man bash`. If the variable is undefined (and I think it is), then this will have the same effect as `exit`, which is equivalent to `exit $?`, where `$?` is the exit code of the last statement, in this case the `echo` on the previous line, which is most probably 0. I think you intended to exit with failure, with non-zero exit code.

---

> ```
>   NUM=$(pdftk $1 dump_data | grep 'NumberOfPages' | awk '{split($0,a,": "); print a[2]}')
> ```

Many problems here:

- You should double-quote `"$1"`, to protect from spaces in the filename
- The quoting in `grep 'NumberOfPages'` is redundant
- Are you sure there won't be more than one lines matching "NumberOfPages"? Just to be safe, I would add `exit` in the Awk command
- The Awk command can be written simpler as `awk -v FS=": " '{print $2}'`

---

> ```
>   COMMSTR=''
> ```

You can simplify to:

```
  COMMSTR=
```

---

> ```
>   for i in $(seq 1 $NUM);
> ```

`seq` is not recommended because it's not portable. You can achieve the same using native Bash functionality:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$NUM; i++));
```

---

> ```
>   $(echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - pageblanche.pdf)
> ```

The `$(...)` wrapping is really pointless, and awful.
No need for `echo ""`, simply `echo` is exactly the same.

---

> ```
>   $(pdftk A=$1 B=pageblanche.pdf cat $COMMSTR output 'mod_'$1)
> ```

Does this work at all? Unfortunately I don't have `pdftk` so cannot try.
Maybe it's fine, but it looks suspicious.

Btw, you don't need the quotes in `'mod_'$1`.
And again, the `$(...)` wrapping is pointless.

---

> ```
>   (pdfnup 'mod_'$1 --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile 'print_'$1)
> ```

As earlier, you don't need those quotes,
and the `(...)` wrapping is pointless.

The same goes for the rest of the code.

#### Suggested implementation

I cannot fully test this because I don't have `pdftk`, but it should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 file1.pdf file2.pdf ..."
  exit 1
fi

for file; do
    NUM=$(pdftk "$file" dump_data | awk -v FS=": " '/NumberOfPages/ { print $2; exit }')
    COMMSTR=

    for ((i=1; i<=$NUM; i++)); do COMMSTR="$COMMSTR A$i B1 "; done

    blank=blank.pdf
    ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - $blank < /dev/null
    pdftk A="$file" B=$blank cat $COMMSTR output mod_"$file"
    pdfnup mod_"$file" --nup 2x1 --landscape --outfile print_"$file"
    rm $blank && rm mod_"$file"
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for your time and work.

Comment: `exit` is not equivalent to `exit 0` it is equivalent to `exit $?`.

Comment: @EtanReisner well spotted! I clarified that point now. Thanks for the review-review, as usual ;-)